# JQuery Change Href link Based on "Disabled" <li> Class

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using a disabled class to prevent people from clicking a link when they do not have access. The JS below does just that, but the problem is they can still see the link and access it. I'm thinking a workaround could be to write another script that replaces the href with javascript:void(0). Any ideas how to accomplish that?

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/internetjason/4nYgb/) - view this to see it in action using a Bootstrap 3 Navbar.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".nav li.disabled a").click(function () {
        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your code with

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $(".nav li.disabled a").attr('href','return false')
 });
```

This will replace the original **href** with newer one

Working [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/internetjason/4nYgb/)

Comment: Perfect, thank you! (I'll mark this as correct in a few minutes when it lets me).